# Recursively create a tree menu from a json object on js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"Sony",
        "Model":"Some_model_acd",
    },
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"Sony",
        "Model":"Some_model_bcd",
    },
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"LG",
        "Model":"Some_model_zcd",
    }, 
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"LG",
        "Model":"Some_model_bcd",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_small_disp",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model 1",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_small_disp",
        "brand_name":"Samsung",
        "Model":"some_model 2",
    }, 
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_large_disp",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model 3",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_large_disp",
        "brand_name":"Samsung",
        "Model":"some_model 4",
    },
]
```

How can I get a menu tree?

> technic -> TV -> Sony -> Some_model_acd
>
> technic -> TV -> Sony -> Some_model_bcd
>
> technic -> TV -> LG -> Some_model_bcd
>
> technic -> TV -> LG ->Some_model_zcd
>
> phones -> smartphones -> Apple -> some_model
>
> phones -> smartphones_small_disp -> Apple -> some_model 1
>
> phones -> smartphones_small_disp -> Samsung -> some_model 2
>
> phones -> smartphones_large_disp -> Apple -> some_model 3
>
> phones -> smartphones_large_disp -> Samsung -> some_model 4

I need an array or object with a hierarchy or html menu code.
Output on php:

```
Array (
    ['technic'] =>  Array (
        ['TV'] =>   Array (
            ['Sony']  => Array (
                [0]  => Some_model_acd,
                [1]  => Some_model_bcd
            ),
            ['LG']  => Array (
                [0]  => Some_model_zcd,
                [1]  => Some_model_bcd
            )
        )
    ),
    ['phones'] =>   Array (
        ['smartphones'] =>  Array (
            ['Apple']  => Array (
                [0]  => some_model
            )
        ),
        ['smartphones_small_disp'] =>   Array (
            ['Apple']  => Array (
                [0]  => some_model 1,
            ),
            ['Samsung']  => Array (
                [0]  => some_model 2,
            )
        ),
        ['smartphones_large_disp'] =>   Array (
            ['Apple']  => Array (
                [0]  => some_model 3,
            ),
            ['Samsung']  => Array (
                [0]  => some_model 4,
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without recursion and instead use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). By using `.reduce()` you can create nested objects based on your properties and add the required `Models` into your arrays.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{type:"technic",product_cat:"TV",brand_name:"Sony",Model:"Some_model_acd"},{type:"technic",product_cat:"TV",brand_name:"Sony",Model:"Some_model_bcd"},{type:"technic",product_cat:"TV",brand_name:"LG",Model:"Some_model_zcd"},{type:"technic",product_cat:"TV",brand_name:"LG",Model:"Some_model_bcd"},{type:"phones",product_cat:"smartphones",brand_name:"Apple",Model:"some_model"},{type:"phones",product_cat:"smartphones_small_disp",brand_name:"Apple",Model:"some_model 1"},{type:"phones",product_cat:"smartphones_small_disp",brand_name:"Samsung",Model:"some_model 2"},{type:"phones",product_cat:"smartphones_large_disp",brand_name:"Apple",Model:"some_model 3"},{type:"phones",product_cat:"smartphones_large_disp",brand_name:"Samsung",Model:"some_model 4"}];

const menu_tree = arr.reduce((a, {type, product_cat, brand_name, Model}) => {
  a[type] = (a[type] || {});
  a[type][product_cat] = (a[type][product_cat] || {});
  const x = a[type][product_cat][brand_name];
  a[type][product_cat][brand_name] = x ? [...x, Model] : [Model];
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(menu_tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this

```js
var data = [
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"Sony",
        "Model":"Some_model_acd",
    },
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"Sony",
        "Model":"Some_model_bcd",
    },
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"LG",
        "Model":"Some_model_zcd",
    }, 
    {
        "type": "technic",
        "product_cat": "TV",
        "brand_name":"LG",
        "Model":"Some_model_bcd",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_small_disp",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model 1",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_small_disp",
        "brand_name":"Samsung",
        "Model":"some_model 2",
    }, 
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_large_disp",
        "brand_name":"Apple",
        "Model":"some_model 3",
    },  
    {
        "type": "phones",
        "product_cat": "smartphones_large_disp",
        "brand_name":"Samsung",
        "Model":"some_model 4",
    },
]

for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
  
  console.log(data[i].type + " -> "+data[i].product_cat+ " -> "+data[i].brand_name+ " -> "+data[i].Model)
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what it is. I updated the question and gave an example of output to php.